# Does the Terraform resource kubernetes_ingress_v1 have a "use_annotation" equivalent?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

We're currently migrating our terraform kubernetes_ingress resource to a kubernetes_ingress_v1 resource. Previously, we had these annotations on the ingress:

```
annotations = {
  "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "alb"
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme" =  "internet-facing"
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn" = var.create_acm_certificate ? aws_acm_certificate.eks_domain_cert[0].id : var.aws_acm_certificate_arn
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports" = "[{\"HTTP\": 80}, {\"HTTPS\":443}]"
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect" = "{\"Type\": \"redirect\", \"RedirectConfig\": { \"Protocol\": \"HTTPS\", \"Port\": \"443\", \"StatusCode\": \"HTTP_301\"}}"
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy" = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06"
  "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path" = "/healthz"
}
```

along with this segment several times in the spec:

```
path {
      backend {
        service_name = "ssl-redirect"
        service_port = "use-annotation"
      }
      path = "/*"
    }
```

However, the kubernetes_ingress_v1 requires a format like:

```
path {
      backend {
        service {
          name = "ssl-redirect"
          port { 
            number = <number_value>
          }
        }
      }
      path = "/*"
    }
```

where port is an actual number and not "use-annotation". Is there any way to replicate this "use-annotation" behavior in a kubernetes_ingress_v1 resource? Or, even better, is there a simpler way to handle this ssl-redirect rule in a kubernetes_ingress_v1?

Answer (score 1):

You can achive that using the following sintaxis:

```
backend {
  service {
    name = "ssl-redirect"
    port {
      name = "use-annotation"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, you need to use the argument *name* instead *port*.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation about this. Have you any reference?

Comment: │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on .terraform/modules/deployment/service/modules/aws-ingress/main.tf line 40, in resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "ingress":
│   40:                 name = "use-annotation"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "name": a number is required.

Comment: What kubernetes provider version are you using? I tested with  v2.20.0  and works. Also you can see this related Github issue:https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/1555#issuecomment-1088316373